# Como fazer um botão com Razor e Css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou tentando fazer um botão em uma determinada pagina.

Porém, todo meu projeto começou com a engine Razor, então gostaria de saber como posso fazer um botão com tal engine, estou tentando fazer assim:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Comercial.ComercialModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div id="Open_menu">
    <span onclick="openNav()">Menu</span>
</div>

<h2>Comercial</h2>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "MenuInicial")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Serviços", "Index", "Servicos")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Comercial", "Index", "Comercial")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Estoque", "Index", "Estoque")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Equipamentos", "Index", "Equipamentos")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Compras", "Index", "Compras")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Fiscal", "Index", "Fiscal")</a>
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Caixa", "Index", "Caixa")</a>
</div>

<div class="but_clientes">
    @Html.ActionLink("Clientes", "Clientes", "Comercial")
</div>
```

Porém, o resultado não é como esperado, ele cria como se fosse um Hyper Link na palavra, e não um botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS:

```
    .but_clientes {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:url(../Image/clientes.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

Ao tentar alterar o codigo html para:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Clientes", "Clientes", "Comercial")
    {
       <input type="button" class="but_clientes" />
    }
</div>
```

Tivemos o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não use nem `<input>`, nem `@Html.ActionLink`. Use:

```
<div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Clientes", "Comercial")">
        <div class="but_clientes">Clientes</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Caramba achei que nunca ia vê-lo em ação...

Answer (score 1):

Pode colocar:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Clientes", "Clientes", "Comercial")
{
    <input type="button" class="but_clientes"/>
}
```

Comment: Amigo, não deu certo, ao realizar o codigo assim, ele aparece o botão mais o actionlink, fiz uma revisao na pergunta. obrigado